# virtualHost Not Creating on RabbitMQ server using application.yml springboot and from config server

Tags: spring-boot, rabbitmq, spring-amqp, spring-cloud-stream, spring-rabbit

Virtualhost are not getting created on RabbitMQ server based on configuration
Do i have make sure VH aka Virtual Hosts on RabbitMQ .
Am i missing some configuration.
Please find the configuration below

application.yml

```
spring:
  rabbitmq:
    host: 127.0.0.1
    virtual-host: /defaultVH
    username: defaultUser
    password: defaultPassword
  cloud:
    stream:
      bindings:
        saviyntSampleQueueA:
          binder: rabbit-A
          contentType: application/x-java-object
          group: groupA
          destination: saviyntSampleQueueA
        saviyntSampleQueueB:
          binder: rabbit-B
          contentType: application/x-java-object
          group: groupB
          destination: saviyntSampleQueueB
      binders:
        rabbit-A:
          defaultCandidate: false
          inheritEnvironment: false
          type: rabbit
          environment:
            spring:
              rabbitmq:
                host: 127.0.0.1
                virtualHost: /vhA
                username: userA
                password: paswdA
                port: 5672
                connection-timeout: 10000
        rabbit-B:
          defaultCandidate: false
          inheritEnvironment: false
          type: rabbit
          environment:
            spring:
              rabbitmq:
                host: 127.0.0.1
                virtualHost: /vhB
                username: userB
                password: paswdB
                port: 5672
                connection-timeout: 10000
```

---

bootstrap.yml

```
############################################
# default settings
############################################
spring:
  main:
    banner-mode: "off"
  application:
    name: demo-service
  cloud:
    config:
      enabled: true #change this to use config-service
      retry:
        maxAttempts: 3
      discovery:
        enabled: false
      fail-fast: true
      override-system-properties: false

server:
  port: 8080
```

---

Added default spring boot added Enable binding

```
@EnableBinding({MessageChannels.class})
@SpringBootApplication
public class Configissue1124Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(Configissue1124Application.class, args);
    }

}
```

---

Now simple straightforward massage channel to to dispatch massage

```
interface MessageChannels {


    @Input("saviyntSampleQueueA")
    SubscribableChannel queueA();

    @Input("saviyntSampleQueueB")
    SubscribableChannel queueB();
}
```

---

When i ran the Boot Application its not creating any Virtualhost on the system . i tried using config server buy providing same configuration but still no luck 
can you please find if some thing am missing.

Thanks  in Advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The AMQP protocol (or RabbitMQ REST API) provides no mechanism to provision virtual hosts from the client.

Virtual hosts must be provisioned manually on the server.

Comment: Thanks Gary , I assume that ,there might be a way to do but I didn’t know. Thanks for confirming.

Comment: But after creating the VirtualHosts manually .
I am still facing issue. Trace is 
`r.c.CachingConnectionFactory       : Attempting to connect to: [127.0.0.1:5672]
SimpleMessageListenerContainer : Restarting Consumer@3179dc04: tags=[[]], channel=null, acknowledgeMode=AUTO local queue size=0'
'Attempting to connect to: [127.0.0.1:5672]`

Comment: I see you are new here. Stack Overflow is a one question/one answer community. Don't ask new questions in comments on an answer; it doesn't help people find questions/answers. Please ask a new question and provide much more information, logs, etc.